# Mysql- counting data in one column group by column2

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table as shown below , i need to find the number of distinct values in column1 group by column 2.

```html
column1 column2
a001 A
a002 A
a001 B
a001 A
a003 B
a004 B
a004 B
A003 A
a003 B
```

My problem is if i am counting column 1 values it is counting values mapped to both A and B as a single count instead of two count, and therefore i am getting wrong count of column 2.
is there any solution to find correct count?

My desired output be like:

```html
count data1 data2
2   a001 A
1   a001 B
1   a002 A
1   a003 A
2   a003 B
2   a004 B
```

Comment: Please post the desired output as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*), COLUMN2 FROM
     ( 
      SELECT DISTINCT column1, column2 FROM table
     ) X

 GROUP BY column2
```

You can get the distinct records first then perform the count and group by.

As per your edit. Shouldn't a

```
select count(*), column2, column1 
from table
group by column2, column1
```

work?

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct column1,column2,sum(count_1) from
(
select column1,column2,1 as count_1 from Table1
)
group by 1,2;
```

try something like this

Comment: whats 2 in this?

Comment: 1 and 2 after group by are column1 and column2 you can also use their names instead

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 SELECT COUNT(column1) AS count ,column1 As data1, column2 AS data2
 FROM youTable 
 GROUP BY column2, column1
```